# Alterar tamanho DialogFragment de acordo com tela Android

Tags: android, dialog, resolução-de-tela

Tenho um formulário de cadastro bem simples que aparece ao clicar em um botão cadastrar. Esse formulário aparece em um `DialogFragment`, porém, com um tamanho muito pequeno.
Zonzando na internet encontrei um código que altera o tamanho dele:

```
  @Override
  public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
```

```
    if (getDialog() == null)
        return;

    int dialogWidth = 200;
    int dialogHeight = 400;

    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);

 }
```

Mas ao que parece ele define esses valores em pixels, então queria saber se tem um jeito calcular a largura da tela(ou view sei lá) e definir o width em 80% da tela e o height deixar aumentar automatico.

Obs: sei que tá meio confuso minhas palavras mas dá para entender meu objetivo com essa pergunta, caso não tenha entendido basta fazer um comentario que eu explico com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Uma Solução pode ser pegar as dimensões da tela do aparelho.**

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int largura = size.x;
int altura = size.y;
```

E a partir delas, efetuar o cálculo para a altura/largura do seu Dialog.

```
larguraDoSeuDialog = largura * 0.8;
alturadoSeuDialog = altura * 0.8;
```

**Obs: o Context acima, seria uma instância da sua activity, se estiver executando o processo dentro dela, pode ser this, senão terá que passar de parâmetro.**

Comment: O width deu certo mas daí é obrigatório colocar o height, e eu queria que ele aumentasse o height automaticamente(algo como o wrap_parent).

Comment: E na linha .getSystemService o android studio mostra o erro non-static method getSystemService(String) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Ajustei o código acima, com relação a altura, mudaria baseado em algum evento?

Comment: Não, é que eu tenho um formulário de cadastro com um titulo Cadastrar, e um TextView e EditText para os campos Nome, Login, Senha e Repetir Senha, além de dois botões um para cancelar o cadastro e outra para cadastrar.

Comment: Então o width tem que ser 80% da tela mas o height tem que aumentar sozinho. Teria alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Então a altura do dialog teria que ser a soma dos componentes dentro dele? algo assim?

Comment: Exatamente, assim como quando definimos a altura de um layout com wrap_parent.

Comment: Quando você monta o dialog, você infla ele a partir de uma view? você pode setar a altura direto na view. Poste o código do dialog para dar uma olhada.

Comment: Nossa cara, não acredito que não fiz isso, é que como eu estou começando no android, não tenho certeza do que dá e não dá pra fazer.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545728/dialog-fragment-with-wrap-content-coming-as-a-full-screen-how-to-make-it-as-a-h

Comment: E eu achei que com o DialogFragment não teria como definir uma altura direto no layout pois tinha lido algo parecido em um forum

Comment: Otimo link, vou dar uma olhada mais a fundo nele, obg.

Comment: Da pra fazer sim, esse link acho que é mais claro pra você implementar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478520/how-to-set-dialogfragments-width-and-height. qualquer coisa poste ai.